# Adding \x0D \x0A to end of record

Tags: perl, vim, file-format

I am writing a Perl program to add \r \n as the 201st and 202nd bytes at the end of a 200 byte record. I am trying to do that this way:

```
use constant REPORT_LINE_LEN => 200;

while(($rc = read $infile, $report_line, REPORT_LINE_LEN(), 0) != 0)
{
    chomp $report_line;
    $report_line .= "\r\n" . "\n";
    print $outfile $report_line;
}
```

The carriage return ^M character is at position 201, and I need a \n at 202, but can't seem to get it placed there without increasing the record's length over 202 bytes. I am verifying the location of the ^M with vim, which indicates the file is still in Unix format.

I have searched a lot of sources out there, and am stumped. Any help would be appreciated including what how the last two bytes might appear in vim.

I am confirming the record length in vim by pressing '$' to get to the end of the line. Right now, it says 201. I'm also using `head -n 1 rmvtape.out | wc -c` to confirm the length of the record where `rmvtape.out` is the file containing these records. The length is `202`.

So, is the ^M invisible in vim in this case?

Comment: Make sure that your output file is using [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html).  Then it should be sufficient to just do "\r\n".

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you're checking your record length?  Also, how long is "over 202 bytes"?

Comment: @Mr.Llama Just edited the file with answer.

Comment: Try `head -c 202 rmvtape.out | od -ax`.  That will give you a hex dump of the line, which should help you sort out your length issues.  Note that I'm using `head -c 202` because `head -n 1` will split on the first `\n` which is technically part of the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $report_line .= "\r\n" . "\n";

You are adding three characters here, e.g `\r`,`\n` and another `\n`.
Omit the last `\n` and everything should be fine, e.g.:

```
$report_line .= "\r\n";
```

Comment: @Steffen_Ulrich I tried this, but the position count in vim goes back to 200, and the ^M is missing in vim. The type is still unix.

Comment: try `warn unpack("H*",$report_line)` to see the octets which are really in the line and check the length with `length($report_line)`. If these give the correct values then `$output` is your problem, e.g. use binmode like @Miller suggested. And don't trust vim, use hexdump to see what's really there.

Comment: @Steffen_Ulrich Your method results in 202 bytes. Confirmed with hexdump.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and comments. This is basically telling me what originally thought, that these are record terminators, not actually part of the record.

Comment: If the ^M is present in the output, but missing in Vim, then probably Vim is actually detecting the file as dos format. Are you certain Vim's value for 'fileformat' when loading this file actually stays at "unix"? If every line ends in \r\n then Vim will by default load it in DOS format.